# Advanced Custom Fields - Issue with Slick Slider in ACF v6 Block

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm having an issue with Slick Slider in the admin preview with ACF 6 using the new block.json way to set up blocks.

I followed an ACF tutorial by Elliot here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/building-a-custom-slider-block-in-30-minutes-with-acf/

In ACF v5 using the old method to add blocks this worked fine, but after updating to ACF 6 and using block.json the block crashes and says 'This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.' if I try to edit it. If I inspect and look in the console I get this:

```
react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'add')
at e.initADA (slick.min.js?ver=6.1.1:1:19335)
at e.init (slick.min.js?ver=6.1.1:1:19101)
at new <anonymous> (slick.min.js?ver=6.1.1:1:2832)
at i.fn.slick (slick.min.js?ver=6.1.1:1:42781)
at initializeBlock (home-slider.js?ver=6.1.1:19:39)
at o (acf.min.js?ver=6.0.5:1:1417)
at Object.doAction (acf.min.js?ver=6.0.5:1:587)
at n.doAction (acf.min.js?ver=6.0.5:1:18745)
at G.renderBlockPreviewEvent (acf-pro-blocks.min.js?ver=6.0.5:1:31066)
at G.componentDidAppend (acf-pro-blocks.min.js?ver=6.0.5:1:30504)
```

I'm using very similar code to the example in the tutorial to inisialise the slider, and it worked fine before I updated from ACF 5 to 6. The code looks like this:

```
(function($){

var initializeBlock = function( $block ) {
    // $block.find('img').doSomething();

    $block.find('.home_banner_content').slick({
        fade: true,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        prevArrow: $('.nav_prev'),
        nextArrow: $('.nav_next'),
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
        speed: 1500,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
    });
}

// Initialize each block on page load (front end).
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.home_slider_block').each(function(){
        initializeBlock( $(this) );
    });
});

// Initialize dynamic block preview (editor).
if( window.acf ) {
    window.acf.addAction( 'render_block_preview/type=home-slider-block', initializeBlock );
} 
})(jQuery);
```

My ACF blocks are registered in my functions.php like this:

```
function register_acf_blocks() {

    // Scripts

    wp_register_script( 'slick', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js', [ 'jquery', 'acf' ] );
    wp_register_script( 'home-slider-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/template-parts/blocks/home-blocks/home-slider-block/home-slider.js', [ 'jquery', 'acf' ] );

    // Styles

    wp_register_style( 'slick-css', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css' );

    // Blocks

    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/template-parts/blocks/home-blocks/home-slider-block' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/template-parts/blocks/page-blocks/intro-block' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/template-parts/blocks/page-blocks/cottage-slider-block' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'register_acf_blocks', 5 );
```

And my json file for the block looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "acf/home-slider-block",
    "title": "Homepage block: Home banner slider",
    "description": "A block to display the main homepage banner.",
    "style": "slick-css",
    "script": ["home-slider-script", "slick"],
    "category": "custom",
    "icon": "format-gallery",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "keywords": [],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "preview",
        "renderTemplate": "home-slider-block.php"
    },
    "align": "full",
    "styles": [],
    "supports": {
        "align": true,
        "anchor": true,
        "alignContent": false,
        "color": {
            "text": false,
            "background": true,
            "link": false
        },
        "alignText": false,
        "fullHeight": false
    },
    "attributes": {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"editorScript": [ "jquery", "slick", "app" ],` to your block.json file.

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#editor-script

Change out the array to call the scripts needed to load in your editor.

Comment: Unfortunately separating out the editor scripts and the front end scripts that still causes the block to crash... I think this is an ACF issue, rather than a general Wordpress one. I've contacted their support and they also couldn't figure it out and eventually just dropped off and stopped replying. I've had to just load scripts on the front end and provide a static representation of the slider in the admin.

Comment: Hey @Laurence,

Very strange, I want to walk through this again to just be sure. In my case, I registered my JS files in my functions.php file. Then in my block.json file I was able to call the handle `"editorScript": [ "jquery", "slick", "app" ],` additionally you could try just changing it to script:[""] ... This was very helpful in figuring it out as well: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/all-possible-block-json-values-and-how-to-use-them/ ... I was able to get my slick slider ACF block working and rendering correctly in the editor. Good luck!